# Input sanitization - passing HTML to JS to PHP to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, special-characters, sanitization

I'm trying to put together a small schedule webpage that lets me directly edit the page, using HTML5's contenteditable, and then pass my changes to a database. Everything seems to be working as far as getting the data there, but if I put in certain special characters, specifically a single quote, everything after it gets dropped from the MySQL cell. I've tried a few things like mysql_real_escape_string() and php's htmlspecialchars, but I can't get anything to accept all special characters. Any suggestions? Or general advice about the app?

The PHP code below pulls the most current value for my Monday list.

```
<h2>Monday</h2>
      <ul class="editme" contenteditable="true">
        <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT monday FROM schedule WHERE ID='1'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo $row['monday'];
        ?>
      </ul>
```

The JavaScript/jQuery/PHP code below will send an update to the MySQL database after the keyup event timer runs. I pass the HTML of the "editme" element to a JS variable and then post that to PHP for updating the db.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.editme').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
      var send = $('.editme').html();
      $.post('schedule.php', {content: send});
        <?php
        $text = $_POST['content'];
        $sql="UPDATE schedule SET monday='$text' WHERE ID='1'";
        if (is_null($text)) {
        }
        else {
          mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
        }
        ?>
    }, 50 );
  });
  var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
      clearTimeout (timer);
      timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: this is "general" as you requested perhaps that. why are you doing updates based on a timer from a keyup?

Comment: @DrewPierce I was using keyup because I wanted the updates to occur when I stopped typing. I put a delay on it because I figured I shouldn't constantly be trying to send an update through. Is this unneeded? Is there a different event handler that I could use?

Comment: i can understand that for select, just not update/insert. for instance, i am typing in the url bar and as i type Google is reading/suggesting from http traffic and reads. i would have a hard time thinking of a case that i want db data changed during that nonsense typing

Comment: but putting that aside, when you have your string that can have embedded single and doubl-quotes, perhaps a real php programmer here (not me) can suggest what to do

Comment: @DrewPierce I guess what I'm kinda going for is the "Google Doc" style updating. Things are constantly saving as you type. The idea is for me to have a simple page with a heading for each day of the week and an editable section below each where I can just start typing out to-do items for the day. Previously, I just used a Google Doc for this, but was unhappy with the lack of viewport responsiveness and allowable customization.

Comment: gotcha. have you looked into `meteor` as a platform? when i first saw a video on it i was laughing hysterically. then i thought about it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PHP's

```
htmlspecialchars($your_string_here)
```

use this instead:

```
htmlentities($your_string_here, ENT_QUOTES);
```

ENT_QUOTES will ensure that both double and single quotes are properly encoded.